# casting a returned value from C++ function

Tags: c++, casting

I have following C++ code snippet

```
inline std::vector<std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>> cloneTensorBuffer(
    const std::vector<const xir::Tensor*>& tensors) 
{
  auto ret = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>>{};
  auto type = xir::DataType::XINT;
  ret.reserve(tensors.size());

  for (const auto& tensor : tensors) {
    ret.push_back(std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>(xir::Tensor::create(
        tensor->get_name(), tensor->get_shape(), xir::DataType{type, 8u})));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I am not clear about the expression:

```
std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>(xir::Tensor::create(
            tensor->get_name(), tensor->get_shape(), xir::DataType{type, 8u}))
```

Is the expression casting the value returned by xir::Tensor::create() to std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor? I am confused since the C++ casting syntax is (type)expression
Can someone explain please.

regards,
-sunil puranik

Comment: Probably taking ownership of a raw pointer. Hard to say without the library code in front of me

Comment: Some people might describe it as a cast.   What it's actually doing is using the return value from `xir::Tensor::create()` with the supplied arguments to initialise an object of type `std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>`.     That initialisation involves calling a `std::unique_ptr` constructor that accepts suitable arguments - which constructor gets called depends on the return type of `xir::Tensor::create()`.  If there is no valid constructor, the result is a diagnosable error.

Comment: And fyi, *"C++ casting syntax is (type)expression"* is a misnomer. Self-respecting C++ engineers avoid explicit conversion casting, (type)expression, opting instead for better C++ language alternatives (static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast, const_cast, the latter two seeing far less limelight than the former in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

This code takes a vector of raw pointers to Tensor objects, and returns a new vector of unique pointers to a new set of Tensor objects. Doesn't look like any explicit casting is taking place.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<xir::Tensor>( // create unique pointer to new Tensor object
    xir::Tensor::create(
        tensor->get_name(),  // created with name and shape of the
        tensor->get_shape(), // tensor pointed at in the original vector
        xir::DataType{type, 8u} // and with unsigned 8-bit XINT datatype
    )
)
```

Regarding casting - please don't consider e.g. `(int)foo` to be C++-style casting - that's legacy C-style casting. Amongst other things it's hard to find by searching a codebase!

C++ has:

- `static_cast`
- `dynamic_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `const_cast`
- implicit conversion

There's more detail on this [at cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).